# Conditionally Display Content if Section

Tags: conditional

How can I conditionally display content if its a specific section?

Currently I'm trying this with no luck:

```
{% if entry.section == 'lettings' %}{{ entry.rentFrequency.label }}{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're close!

[SectionModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/SectionModel) has '[name](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/models/SectionModel.php#L182)' and '[handle](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/models/SectionModel.php#L183)' attributes and one of those is probably what you're looking for.

```
{% if entry.section.handle == 'lettings' %}
    {{ entry.rentFrequency.label }}
{% endif %}
```